# Viber bot ошибка при отправке share-phone кнопки, нормально?

Tags: api, бот, viber

Почитал в документации и на форумах что кнопка для получения контакта работает только в мобильной версии, в десктопной возвращает текст, и нужно задать его в ActionBody, так и делаю:

```
[
'Columns' => 6,
'Rows' => 1,
'Text' => "Отправить телефон,
'ActionType' => 'share-phone',
'ActionBody' => "Action body text"
]
```

Но при отправке мне даже не приходит текст - только ошибка:

{"status":3,"status_message":"keyboard is not valid. [instance value ("share-phone") not found in enum (possible values: ["reply","open-url",""])]","chat_hostname":"SN-CHAT-09_"}

Легко можно понять: ответ говорит что не существует никаких других кнопок кроме ссылки и reply.
Это просто странно, пробовал и с телефона отправлять запрос, удалял бота и начинал с телефона чат - один результат. Объясните пожалуйста, возможно я что-то не так делаю.

**Тест из документации:** ActionType    optional. Type of action pressing the button will perform. Reply - will send a reply to the PA. open-url - will open the specified URL and send the URL as reply to the PA. See reply logic for more details. Note: location-picker and share-phone are not supported on desktop, and require adding any text in the ActionBody parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел информацию в самом API. Для конретной работы нужно запретить пользователям со старыми версиями вайбера просматривать сообщения параметром 'min_api_version' = 7; к примеру. Когда указал параметр - заработало